# regex grouping fails with more than one group

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have this regex, for C#. The alert portion works fine, but when I add the msg group, 
it just hangs with cursor blinking on command line.

What have I missed, they both work by themselves, but not in full group map.

```
string pattern = @"(?<action>alert\s+(?:tcp|udp|icmp)\s+(.*?)*[(])\s+" +
                                     @"(?<msg>msg[:](.*?)\[;\s*])";
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    Match res = rgx.Match(rule);
```

I'm trying to match a string like `#alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 12345:12346 (msg:"MALWARE-BACKDOOR netbus getinfo"; flow:to_server,established;`

Comment: What is the input on which you're running it?  I've seen [sometimes even very simple] regexes that take hours to run on some particular input.  It's possible that when you add msg regex part, regex becomes extremely inefficient.  Please post input string against which regex is run to figure it out.  Also, look into some online regex testers (www.regex101.com is one of such) or desktop utilities like RegexBuddy that let you debug regex to understand how it is executing.

Comment: The obvious part that stands out to me is the unmatched unescaped bracket at the end portion: `\[;\s*]`.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you'd like to match? Also, when matching them by themselves, are you using an _exact_ copy?

Comment: @SQB  the new pattern still hangs, 

                                                                   `string pattern = @"(?<action>alert\s+(?:tcp|udp|icmp)\s+(.*?)*[(])\s+" +
                      @"(?<msg>msg:(.*?);)"`

what i am looking for is in the string 

#alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 12345:12346 (msg:"MALWARE-BACKDOOR netbus getinfo"; flow:to_server,established;

Comment: @SQB  Thanks, i cant believe i missed that, that fixed it, it now parses correctly. i will add the rest of the groups now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `(.*?)*` in your first group. Try `(.*?)` instead.

When matching *without* the second group, that just matches till the end of the line. However, when adding the second group, it needs to back off to allow the second group to match. Since you've got two quantifiers interacting, there are a bazillion ways to match until it has backed off sufficiently to allow the second group to match.

An example. Let's say you're matching the string `abc` with `(.*?)*`. The ways for that to match are:

```
(a)(b)(c)
(a)(bc)
(ab)(c)
(abc)
```

And that's not counting the possible empty strings that regex might match in between (because `.*` will match an empty string as well).
Trying to match one character more, say `abcd`, yields as possible matches:

```
(a)(b)(c)(d)
(a)(b)(cd)
(a)(bc)(d)
(a)(bcd)
(ab)(c)(d)
(ab)(cd)
(abc)(d)
(abcd)
```

So the number of possible matches doubles for every character added.